# Extensible interface for different models

Tags: api, design-patterns

I'm designing an API which defines a common interface between two different models. The common interface is a `Peer` which represents an external system to communicate with. A `Client` is a `Peer` which attempts to establish a connection to a specific address. And a `Server` is a `Peer` which accepts connections in from a subnet of addresses.

```
public interface Peer {
    void send(Message m);
}

public interface Client extends Peer {
    InetAddress getAddress();
}

public interface Server extends Peer {
    String getSubnet();
}
```

Applications that use this API will work with `Peer` objects. Because of this, their logic will constantly require type checking to pull information unique to the `Peer` to perform their work. Furthermore, if there ever became another type of `Peer` applications may break.

```
Peer p = incomingMessage.getPeer();

if (p instanceof ClientPeer) {
    //do client peer stuff
} else if (p instanceof ServerPeer) {
    //do server peer stuff
} else {
    //uh oh...
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to design this? One that does not require constant type checking, and isn't flawed from expanding itself further with new types of `Peer`?

Comment: Perhaps the ClientPeer and ServerPeer should do their own stuff, or perhaps they do not be need to sub types of peer if they are always doing different things.

Answer (score 0):

the client code shouldn't have to do switch statements like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern is an approach you might want to implement.

Have an interface 'peer' that has some abstract methods. Then have a builder/factory that 'creates' an 'instance' of the peer they want. Then you store that as your 'peer' variable. This way the Client only has to learn 1 API (of 'peer') and not have to care about all the different types of peers.

However, @dbugger is correct that if the APIs for a 'client' and a 'server' are so different than they shouldn't be extending the same class/interface anyways . If they DO have a SUBSET of methods that overlap, then make a more limited interface that concerns that functionality.

This sounds like a Bit-torrent type scenario, and "servers" in BT are NOT clients. They CAN run client code, but that is a separate process running on the same machine, not a part of the server. (this might help you clean up your logic of what a 'peer' is)

Answer (score 0):

> Applications that use this API will work with Peer objects. Because of this, their logic will constantly require type checking to pull information unique to the Peer to perform their work.

If so they do not really work with peer objects or the api of Peer should be re-designed, because they need information that a peer does not provide.

Usually you get around this by extracting a common api and move the conditional code into the subclasses. E.g.

```
public class ClientPeer implements Client {

     public void findAGoodName(){
         //do client peer stuff
     }
}
```

Sometimes you will get into the situation that the "do client peer stuff" needs information that only the method's caller has. In this case introduce another interface. E.g.

```
public class ClientPeer implements Client {

     public void findAGoodName(CallerData callerData){
         //do client peer stuff
     }
}
```

**PS**: Find good names for the classes, methods and so on.